# Angular modal service not displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to set up [angular modal service](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service) on my web app, but whenever I click on my button it does not appear. What am I doing wrong?

**Builder View**

```
<div ng-controller="BuilderController as vm">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="vm.showExportModal()">Export</button>
</div>
```

**Builder Controller**

```
angular.module('myWebApp')
  .controller('BuilderController', function ($scope, BuilderService) {    
    var vm = this;

    vm.showExportModal = function() {
      BuilderService.showExportModal();
    }; 
  });
```

**Builder Service**

```
angular.module('myWebApp')
  .service('BuilderService', function (ModalService) {

    var builderService = {
      showExportModal: showExportModal
    };
    return builderService;

    function showExportModal() {
      ModalService.showModal({
        template: "<div>Fry lives in {{futurama.city}}</div>",
        controller: function() {
          this.city = "New New York";
        },
        controllerAs : "futurama"
      })
    };

  });
```

Comment: Have you added the service as a dependency to your app?

`angular.module('myWebApp', ['angularModalService']);`

Comment: What is Modal service? Are there any errors? The questions doesn't contain enough details. Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A plunk or a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine in this snippet, I suggest checking you have injected it as a dependency in your app.

Please also note you need the correct modal template to display a modal instead of the template you have provided to the directive.

```js
angular.module('myWebApp', ['angularModalService']);

angular.module('myWebApp')
  .controller('BuilderController', function($scope, BuilderService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.showExportModal = function() {
      BuilderService.showExportModal();
    };
  });

angular.module('myWebApp')
  .service('BuilderService', function(ModalService) {

    var builderService = {
      showExportModal: showExportModal
    };
    return builderService;

    function showExportModal() {
      ModalService.showModal({
        template: "<div>Fry lives in {{futurama.city}}</div>",
        controller: function() {
          this.city = "New New York";
        },
        controllerAs: "futurama"
      })
    };

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://dwmkerr.github.io/angular-modal-service/angular-
modal-service.js"></script>

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="myWebApp">
  <div ng-controller="BuilderController as vm">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="vm.showExportModal()">Export</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @cnotherfield I have done all of this (adding it as a dependency in `app.js` file but nothing seems to appear when I click on the button